# Difference of Execution in Function and Without Function (Return Variable)

Tags: python, function, arguments

So I have to following code with the goal to add some offset to measurement data.

This works as planned:

```
IndexMax = [3, 10, 20, 30]
IndexMax2 = [3, 10, 20, 30] #Just for Computing purposes


for x in range(0, len(IndexMax)):
  if x == 0:
      IndexMax2[0] = 0; #First Data has no Offset per Definition
  elif len(IndexMax2) >= 1: #The 
      IndexMax2[x] = IndexMax[x-1] + IndexMax2[x-1]
      tmp = IndexMax2


print('Offsets are ' + str(tmp))
```

The Correct Output is given:

```
Offsets are [0, 3, 13, 33]
```

But what does not work is the same as a funtion with Indexmax as an argument:

```
def Offsetcalcalculater(IndexMax):
     IndexMax = IndexMax
     IndexMax2 = IndexMax


     for x in range(0, len(IndexMax)):
         if x == 0:
              IndexMax2[0] = 0; #First Data has no Offset per Definition
         elif len(IndexMax2) >= 1: #The 
              IndexMax2[x] = IndexMax[x-1] + IndexMax2[x-1]
              tmp = IndexMax2
     return IndexMax2
```

Calling it with

```
IndexMaxtest = [3, 10, 20, 30]
IndexMax2 = Offsetcalcalculater(IndexMaxtest)
```

leads to:

```
IndexMax2 [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Why does the function not behave in the same way as the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a shallow copy of `IndexMax`
Both `IndexMax` and `IndexMax2` referring same list

```
IndexMax    Indexmax2
#    |            |
#    |            |
#     \          /  
#      \        /
#       IndexMax
```

To solve this use `.copy` to make a copy of the list.

```py
def Offsetcalcalculater(IndexMax):
     IndexMax = IndexMax
     IndexMax2 = IndexMax.copy() #---->


     for x in range(0, len(IndexMax)):
         if x == 0:
              IndexMax2[0] = 0; #First Data has no Offset per Definition
         elif len(IndexMax2) >= 1: #The 
              IndexMax2[x] = IndexMax[x-1] + IndexMax2[x-1]
              tmp = IndexMax2
     return IndexMax2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IndexMax = [3, 10, 20, 30]
IndexMax2 = [3, 10, 20, 30]
```

are two references to two different lists. If you change one, the second one won't change.

```
 IndexMax = IndexMax
 IndexMax2 = IndexMax
```

on the other hand, are two references to the same list. Changing something in `IndexMax` will lead to the same change in `IndexMax2`